# SearchView: Suggestion's list height not change

Tags: android, searchview

I have fragment with `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` (not in toolbar).

When I click on searchView then open suggestion list. When I input some text (filtering) the suggestion list show fitler result. And as result change it's height.

The question is: Is it possible when input text to NOT change height of suggestion list?

Comment: It's a dfifferent questions!!!

Comment: OK, reopened...

Comment: OK. Thank you!!!